# SQL Developer script output is cutoff with margin issues

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having an issue where the margins of the output are being affected.
Instead of everything coming across the the screen, it's outputting parts on top of each other.
How do I get rid of the bar in the pic? I assume that's the culprit, but have been unable to fix this issue. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: maybe interesting? [How to Format Your Script Output in SQL Developer…By Default](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/05/how-to-format-your-script-output-in-sql-developer-by-default/). see `linesize`?

Answer (score 5):

Go to the menu Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Display, and uncheck the "Show visible right margin" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SET LINESIZE` parameter in your worksheet.

```
SET LINESIZE 400
```

The value I mentioned here is just for illustrative purpose and it might or might not work for you. Nonetheless, this is how you fix your issue of making sure that individual records do not overlap.

The faint vertical line you see in your window doesn't affect your result view once you set a proper linesize for your worksheet session.

Answer (score 1):

The below settings worked for me -

```
set long 100000;
set longchunksize 100000;
```